# Endless spinner when trying to update Xcode in App Store

Tags: mac-appstore, mac-mini

I'm trying to update Xcode on my Mac mini.

When I click the **Update** button in the App Store, a spinner appears, but nothing else happens.

[image: Eternal spinner screenshot]

I have seen this before, and I think that possibly upgrading of the App Store fixed it.  There's no App Store update this time.

I am trying an OS upgrade to EL Capitan.  Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: You can't upgrade to the latest version of XCode without El Capitan.

Comment: I had to throw away it eventually, and reinstall

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I had to do

- **Upgrade OS X** to the latest

  - This stopped the eternal spinner - instead the spinner showed for a second, then nothing happened
  - In the past, updating the App Store itself helped
- Go to the **Updates tab** and click **UPDATE ALL**

  - App Store asked me for my credentials then ran all upgrades, including Xcode

[image]

Comment: This worked for me - had to upgrade vie about this mac > software update... It's nice that there isn't anything to prevent you trying and failing, and then absolutely no feedback to tell you this is the case :)

Answer (score 3):

You might have to update your macOS version.
Each Xcode version has a minimum macOS version requirement to work.
You can find out if your current version of macOS supports the version of Xcode you want to install here: [Xcode 7.0 - 10.x (since Free On-Device Development)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_10.x_(since_Free_On-Device_Development))

In my case the infinite loading spinner for the Xcode update was appearing because Xcode 9.4.1 isn't supported on the macOS El Capitan. I updated to the latest version of macOS and I managed to update Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I've done an `Update All` and XCode still shows an `Update` button.  I'm on El Capitan and XCode version 8.x.  I know v9.x of XCode is out but I don't know if it's available for El Capitan.  I presume so since otherwise I wouldn't see the `Update` button, but clicking it just make the spinner run forever and it never updates